# Duplex printing stopped working (Lexmark X543)

Tags: printing, lexmark, duplex-printing

The duplex printing has been working before, but now it has stopped working when printing from ubuntu (it works fine if I print from my Mac). I have no idea what I might have tampered with in order to make it stop working (actually I don't remember tampering with anything at all).

I think I've looked in the obvious places: in Printer Properties/Printer Options, Duplex is set to "Duplex - Long Edge". Similarily if I log in via http it says "Sides Duplex: 2", "Duplex Binding: Long-edge".

Where do I continue troubleshooting this? I'm using 15.04.